# prisma One-To-Many relationship isn't working

Tags: javascript, rest, next.js, prisma, prisma2

I really know that the problem Is with me and Prisma's one-to-many relationship is working alright but just bear with me please.

***1. This is the model's part where I have the problem:***

```
model Product{
  Id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  Uuid String @unique @default(uuid())
  Title String
  BrandName String?
  Thumbnails Thumbnail[] // one to many between thumbnail and Product
  Price Float
  DiscountRate Float?
  Category Category @relation(fields: [CategoryId], references: [Id]) // one to many between Category and Product
  CategoryId Int // The field containing the ID of the Category of this product
  Status Status
  Favorite Boolean @default(false)
  Stock Int @default(0)
  Item Item[] // one to many between Item and Product
}

model Cart{
  Id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  Items Item[] // one to many between Item and Cart
}

model Item{
  Id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  Product Product @relation(fields: [ProductId], references: [Id]) // one to many between Item and Product
  ProductId Int  
  Quantity Int
  Cart Cart? @relation(fields: [CartId],references: [Id]) // one to many between Cart and Item
  CartId Int?
}
```

***2. API Code (NextJs)***

```
// addItem.js 

import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export default async (req, res) => {
  
  let PrId = req.body.prodId;
  let Qte = req.body.Qte;
  let newItem = await prisma.item.create({
    data:{
      Quantity: Qte,
      Product:{
        connect:{
          Id: PrId,
        },
      }, 
      Cart:{
        connect:{
          Id: req.body.cartId
        }
      }
    },
  });

  return res.status(200).json(newItem);
};
```

***3. Problem's explanation:***

Now the thing is that I have multiple carts in the database, each cart contains Items as shown in the model. The real problem is with creating new items:

- Adding the first item goes smoothly.
- When I wanna add another item **which is connected to the same Product** I get an error as follows:

```
Unique constraint failed on the constraint: `Item_ProductId_key`
    at RequestHandler.handleRequestError (C:\Users\Bachar\Desktop\First_Freelance\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:30873:13)  
    at RequestHandler.request (C:\Users\Bachar\Desktop\First_Freelance\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:30856:12)
    at async PrismaClient._request (C:\Users\Bachar\Desktop\First_Freelance\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:31836:16)        
    at async __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/addItem.js:12:19)
    at async Object.apiResolver (C:\Users\Bachar\Desktop\First_Freelance\node_modules\next\dist\server\api-utils\node.js:367:9)
    at async DevServer.runApi (C:\Users\Bachar\Desktop\First_Freelance\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:474:9)
    at async Object.fn (C:\Users\Bachar\Desktop\First_Freelance\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:736:37)
    at async Router.execute (C:\Users\Bachar\Desktop\First_Freelance\node_modules\next\dist\server\router.js:252:36)
    at async DevServer.run (C:\Users\Bachar\Desktop\First_Freelance\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:381:29)
    at async DevServer.run (C:\Users\Bachar\Desktop\First_Freelance\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:724:20) {        
  code: 'P2002',
  clientVersion: '4.5.0',
  meta: { target: 'Item_ProductId_key' },
  page: '/api/addItem'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thanks for anyone who viewed this.
I had a migration before the one above where the `ProductId` inside the `Cart` model flagged as `@unique`, Which I removed in this last migration. The problem was that the database wasn't in sync with this last Prisma Schema even after using `npx prisma migrate dev`.
I copied the schema file, removed the whole prisma folder, used the `npx prisma init`  to generate a new folder then pasted the schema, migrated and voila!!

***Anyways if anyone has an idea on how to do it without removing the schema file It would be a big help to tell me, cuz that would have been one hell of a day if the app was already in production.***

Comment: Hey @Bachar ELkarni, when you executed `npx prisma migrate dev` did you get an output of `Your database is now in sync with your schema.`? If not, then the database would not have been in sync with the schema file. If yes, did you have to reset your database?  Ideally there should be no need to remove the prisma folder.

Comment: @NurulSundarani I got the message that says that the database is in sync with the schema but it wasn't actually the case, even re-running all the migration didn't work so i had to erase the prisma folder and generate it again from scratch